# How to make front page temporarily show content of internal page

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I'm building a Wordpress site with /blog/ as the posts page, with ACF and other options on the page.  Client wants to launch the blog part of the site on their current non-wordpress site as a temporary basis until the rest of the site is built.  I thought it would be relatively easy...

First, upload the Wordpress install to /blog on the live site (that part worked great)

Then make the /blog page the front page via Settings -> Reading... and that didn't work at all.  Homepage and Posts page can't both be "Blog", setting homepage to "Latest posts" removes the ability to edit the ACF fields and other issues.  I spent a few hours trying to come up with some redirect to just show /blog/ as the front page of the Wordpress install, but nothing I tried worked.

It feels like it should be easy to do, but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both a posts loop and ACF fields on a page, I *believe* you need to have a real page for it, put a loop on it, and then designate that as your front page. It sounds like you already have this page set up. Select it as your front page.

You will temporarily not be using the posts page setting, so it does not need to be set to "blog". Someone is free to correct me if I'm wrong, but putting a page there mostly changes it's template hierarchy to look for home.php.

Comment: Yes I did have a real page set up, though once I set it as my home page, a lot of things broke.  I think the only way to get it to work properly will be to do an htaccess trick... to make the internal page show as the front.  Though I don't have that working yet.